# Need step-by-step help adding jquery lightbox to my code using dreamweaver

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dreamweaver, lightbox

I bought a template, that I've been editing in Dreamweaver.
I wanted to add the pop-up function that lightbox has, and tried on my own but can't figure it out.

I could use some step-by-step instructions explained to an idiot..(i.e. a 'this code goes in line 26' type deal)...if you feel like explaining why, that'd be awesome too, so this way i can learn what's going on in my template's coding...

The jquery lightbox plugin I was using is the leandro vieira one, and below is the code for one of the particular pages on my site. I don't know if you need to also edit any of the .js files .css files? am i providing enough info for you to help me?  Anyway, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: which part of the page should be showing the lightbox?  The more button under details?

Comment: hey will, thanks for replying...
sorry i didn't specify where..

i would like for it to be the images...so when i click on the image, then the lightbox is shown...

eventually what i would also like to be able to do, is click on a text link, and there would be a popup of any further text. but probably best to focus on one thing at a time for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the zip file from

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Find the file jquery.lightbox-0.5.pack.js and stick it in your js folder in your project.

After the existing line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

put the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.pack.js"></script>
```

Find the css file in the zip, jquery.lightbox-0.5.css, and put it in your css folder.

After the existing line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
```

put the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
```

Replace the line:

```
<img src="images/spec_offer1.jpg" alt="" />
```

with

```
<a class="lightbox" href="spec_offer1.jpg"><img src="spec_offer1_thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

(you have to create the thumbnail image yourself)

Then, just above the closing body tag add the following:

```
<script>
    $('.lightbox').lightBox();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks again will...
i did what you said, but when i click on the image, it doesnt pop-up, but rather it opens a new page?

Comment: Interesting!  Can you publish it to the web so I can see?

Comment: your lightbox code & css doesn't seem to be on the server.  Could you upload that too?

Comment: all the files in your js folder, and all the files in your css folder.  the two lightbox files are not on the server, I think it might be as simple as that.

Comment: i uploaded jquery.lightbox-0.5.pack.js to my js folder, 
and jquery.lightbox-0.5.css into my css folder...

what else should i be uploading?

Comment: haha, then it's my fault.  The example code I gave you uses 0.4.  Change the 0.4s in the html I gave you to 0.5 and it should all work.  (the darkside of copy paste)

Comment: I think you also need to copy all the lightbox images into your /images folder

Comment: awsome, now i got it...had to also add '.pack' into the mix....thanks for such a quick response and the help man..appreciate it...

so i should just change these lines of code on all my pages so i can do the same on them?

Comment: ah, here's a question while you're around....if i want to utilize the 'next' and 'previous' buttons, how would that be arranged?

Comment: It should just work.  as you add more images to your page...  Now you want to tick this answer as correct. :)

Comment: ah, yup..you're right...
will up-tick it...i was trying to figure out how i can give you some points for helping me

Comment: Awesome!  I got a tonne of help today on server fault so am just paying back into the karma bank.